# Значение слова "сноб"

Tags: семантика

Что же такое сноб? Очень много толкований.

Comment: Смотрите поиск, на сайте уже около десяти ответов .

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1

Answer (score 2):

Почему много... Смотрим в словарь Кузнецова, например:

СНОБ, -а; м. [англ. snob] 1. В России до 1917 г.: о человеке, стремившемся строго следовать вкусам, манерам и т.п. высшего общества и с пренебрежением относившемся ко всему другому. 2. Неодобр. Человек, считающий себя носителем высшей интеллектуальности и изысканных вкусов. <Снобистский, -ая, -ое. С-ие рассуждения. С-ие вкусы.

А какие еще толкования вы знаете?